# Synchronizing a non-atomic array using atomic variables and memory fences

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, synchronization

I've been trying to build a simple (i.e. inefficient) MPMC queue using only std C++ but I'm having trouble getting the underlying array to synchronize between threads. A simplified version of the queue is:

```
constexpr int POISON = 5000;
  class MPMC{
    std::atomic_int mPushStartCounter;
    std::atomic_int mPushEndCounter;
    std::atomic_int mPopCounter;
    static constexpr int Size = 1<<20;
    int mData[Size];
  public:
    MPMC(){
      mPushStartCounter.store(0);
      mPushEndCounter.store(-1);
      mPopCounter.store(0);
      for(int i = 0; i < Size;i++){
          //preset data with a poison flag to
          // detect race conditions
          mData[i] = POISON;
        }
    }
    void push(int x) {
      int index = mPushStartCounter.fetch_add(1);
      mData[index] = x;//Race condition
      atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
      int expected = index-1;
      while(!mPushEndCounter.compare_exchange_strong(expected, index, std::memory_order_acq_rel)){std::this_thread::yield();}
    }

    int pop(){
      int index = mPopCounter.load();
      if(index <= mPushEndCounter.load(std::memory_order_acquire) && mPopCounter.compare_exchange_strong(index, index+1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)){
        return mData[index]; //race condition
      }else{
        return pop();
      }
    }
  };
```

It uses three atomic variables for synchronization:

- `mPushStartCounter` that is used by `push(int)` to determine which location to write to.
- `mPushEndCounter` that is used to signal that `push(int)` has finished writing up to that point int the array to `pop()`.
- `mPopCounter` that is used by `pop()` to prevent double pops from occurring.

In `push()`, between writing to the array `mData` and updating `mPushEndCounter` I've put a release barrier in an attempt to force synchronization of the `mData` array.

The way I understood [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) this should force a Fence-Atomic Synchronization. where

- the CAS in `push()` is an 'atomic store X',
- the load of `mPushEndCounter` in `pop()` is an 'atomic acquire operation Y' ,
- The release barrier 'F' in `push()` is 'sequenced-before X'.

In which case cppreference states that

> In this case, all non-atomic and relaxed atomic stores that are sequenced-before F in thread A will happen-before all non-atomic and relaxed atomic loads from the same locations made in thread B after Y.

Which I interpreted to mean that the write to `mData` from `push()` would be visible in `pop()`. This is however not the case, sometimes `pop()` reads uninitialized data. I believe this to be a synchronization issues because if I check the contents of the queue afterwards, or via breakpoint, it reads correct data instead.

I am using clang 6.0.1, and g++ 7.3.0.

I tried looking at the generated assembly but it looks correct to me: the write to the array is followed by a `lock cmpxchg` and the read is preceded by a check on the same variable. Which to the best of my limited knowledge should work as expected on x64 because

- Loads are not reordered with other loads, hence the load from array can not speculate ahead of reading the atomic counter.
- stores are not reordered with other stores, hence the `cmpxchg` always comes after the store to array.
- `lock cmpxchg` flushes the write-buffer, cache, etc. Therefore if another thread observes it as finished, one can rely on cache coherency to guarantee that write to the array has finished. I am not *too* sure that this is correct however.

---

I've posted a runable test on [Github](https://gist.github.com/RDeckers/5089f908b369636c2155e408326008fa#file-mpmc-cpp-L10). The test code involves 16 threads, half of which push the numbers 0 to 4999 and the other half read back 5000 elements each. It then combines the results of all the readers and checks that we've seen all the numbers in [0, 4999] exactly 8 times (which fails) and scans the underlying array once more to see if it contains all the numbers in [0, 4999] exactly 8 times (which succeeds).

Comment: Suppose three threads call `push` at the same time. They have `index` of 0, 1 and 2 correspondingly. Suppose the last of these gets to the compare-exchange loop first. The first call fails - and as a side effect, `expected` is updated with the current value of `mPushEndCounter`. Then the second call succeeds, and `mPushEndCounter` jumps straight to 1. `pop` then may read from slots 0 and 1 before they got assigned. Bottom line is, you are using compare-exchange-based loops incorrectly.

Comment: `atomic_thread_fence` is a red herring - strong atomic operations should already provide all the fences you need. You simply have logical errors.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. I completely glossed over the fact that CAS updates `expected` on a failure. Works as expected when I reset it.